# I'm trying to run my microservice on kubernetes and docker

Tags: kubernetes, nestjs, docker-desktop

I have an application that works as follows I have a gateway that accesses some services in nestjs to access a request is as follows: **http://ip-gateway:port-gateway/url-service**

I just want to run them on Kubernetes I've already created the images and managed to run some pods but I don't know how to access the service in front of the gateway.

My deployment gateway:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-gateway
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-gateway
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-gateway
        image: api-gateway
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 3000
```

My gateway service:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  labels:
    run: my-gateway
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
```

My gateway endpoints:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.x.x
    ports:
      - port: 3000
```

My deployment adm-contact:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      run: my-adm-contact
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        run: my-adm-contact
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: my-adm-contact
        image: adm-contact
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8879
```

My service adm-contact:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact
  labels:
    run: my-adm-contact
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8879
    protocol: TCP
```

My endpoints adm-contact:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.x.x
    ports:
      - port: 8879
```

The endpoints when I run my **adm-contact** service it changes the running status to **CrashLoopBackOff**

Comment: Have you looked at the logs for the failing pods (using `kubectl logs ...`)? What do you see?

Comment: Thanks I found a database connection error. my database is a container do you have any problems accessing it within kubernetes?

Comment: You haven't provided any information in your question that would allow us to diagnose a database connection error.

Comment: I was missing a file thank you very much

Comment: Why do you define Endpoint resources? Use selectors in your services and the Endpoints will get created automatically.

Comment: I wanted to set an ip for each pod I'm using micro service with nestjs and it puts the ip with the port for each service but I'm having an ip conflict. The gateway ip is 192.168.18.8:3000 and the service ip is 192.168.18.8:8879. The error I'm trying in the service is Error: listen **EADDRNOTAVAIL: address not available 192.168.x.x:8879** thanks