# I'm trying to convert my application to kubenetes and NGINX Ingress Controller

Tags: node.js, nginx, kubernetes

I have a microservices with nodejs and mysql and I'm a few days trying to use this application in kubernetes with scalability. I converted each service to an image of a POD, in fact I have a gateway that applies TCP traffic to each service. My problem is that when I run a port-forward for each pod: **kubectl port-forward my-gateway --address 192.168.18.x 3000** and **kubectl port-forward my-adm-contact --address 192.168.18.x 8181** this works normally but how I can't do a **port-forward** to multiple pods in a single command I decided to use NGINX Ingress Controller I installed it with helm but it only gives 404 Not Found on the page. I will put my structure below

followed my gateway:

```
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppController } from './app.controller';
import { ClientsModule, Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppService } from './app.service';

@Module({
  imports: [
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'SERVICE_A',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8888,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'SERVICE_B',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8889,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'USER',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8887,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'USER_LOGIN',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8886,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'USER_CREATE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8885,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'USER_UPDATE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8884,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'CATEGORY',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8883,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'CATEGORY_BUSCA',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8882,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'CATEGORY_PRODUCT',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8881,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'USER_SENHA',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8880,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'ADM_CONTACT',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8181,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'LOCATION',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8878,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT_STAR',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8877,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT_SINGLE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8876,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PRODUCT_GET_STAR',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8875,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PURCHASE_CREATE',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8874,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PURCHASE_GET_CART',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8873,
        },
      },
      {
        name: 'PURCHASE_GET',
        transport: Transport.TCP,
        options: {
          host: "192.168.18.x",
          port: 8870,
        },
      }
    ]),
  ],
  controllers: [AppController],
  providers: [AppService],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

contact service:

```
import { NestFactory } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Transport } from '@nestjs/microservices';
import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { Logger } from '@nestjs/common';

const logger = new Logger();

async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.createMicroservice(AppModule, {
    transport: Transport.TCP,
    options: {
      host: "0.0.0.0",
      port: 8181,
    },
  });
  app.listen(() => logger.log('Microservice ADM CONTACT is listening'));
}
bootstrap();
```

kubernetes service contact:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 8181
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8181
```

kubernetes POD contact:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact
  labels:
    app: my-adm-contact
    name: my-adm-contact
spec:
  containers:
  - image: my-adm-contact
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    name: my-adm-contact
    ports:
    - containerPort: 8181
      protocol: TCP
  restartPolicy: Always
```

kubernetes endpoints contact:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  name: my-adm-contact-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.18.x
    ports:
      - port: 8181
```

kubernetes service gateway:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name:  my-gateway-service
  namespace: default
spec:
  ports:
  - port: 3000
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 3000
```

kubernetes POD gateway:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
  labels:
    app: my-gateway
    name: my-gateway
spec:
  containers:
  - image: api-gateway
    imagePullPolicy: Never
    name: my-gateway
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3000
      protocol: TCP
  restartPolicy: Always
```

kubernetes endpoints gateway:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Endpoints
metadata:
  # the name here should match the name of the Service
  name: my-gateway-service
subsets:
  - addresses:
      - ip: 192.168.18.x
    ports:
      - port: 3000
```

kubernetes ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
#  defaultBackend:
#    service:
#      name: my-gateway-service
#      port:
#        number: 3000
  rules:
  - host: host.docker.internal
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-gateway-service
            port:
              number: 3000
      - path: /adm-contact
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: my-adm-contact-service
            port:
              number: 8181
```

my ingress-nginx-tcp:

```
apiVersion: v1
data:
  "3000": default/my-gateway-service:3000
  "8181": default/my-adm-contact-service:8181
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: ingress-nginx
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: ingress-nginx
  creationTimestamp: "2022-06-28T00:00:28Z"
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: controller
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/part-of: ingress-nginx
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 1.2.1
    helm.sh/chart: ingress-nginx-4.1.4
  name: ingress-nginx-tcp
  namespace: ingress-nginx
  resourceVersion: "264565"
  uid: 2284f6eb-53f9-4d8c-9f62-6ad303120f63
```

Does anyone know how to help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is there a specific reason you've set the `ImagePullPolicy` to `Never` in your pod specifications? Perhaps try leaving it to default and remove that.

Also, did you ensure that your services are running fine in the cluster? You can try to bypass the `ingress` temporarily, and try to access the services directly from outside your cluster by setting the service type to `NodePort`[see docs here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#type-nodeport) and using `<Node-IP>:<nodePort>` to access it. Just to verify the problem is not in the service backend itself? It appears to me that, that is the issue here.

Comment: I'm using docker desktop and my images are local by that use ImagePullPolicy to Never. The big issue is that each url is a service so I don't think it would work using <node-ip>:<node-port> for example: `192.168.18.8:3000/adm-contact` where the ip and port is the gateway to url `/adm-contact` invokes the service

Comment: I'm using docker kubernetes, it has some limitation too like the loadbalancer I don't know if <ip-node> would work properly

Comment: I think it's worth a try. It would work.

Comment: I'll try to implement nodeport then I'll give you feedback

Comment: Perfect @Noor Muhammad Malik perfect it worked I put my ipv4 plus nodeport and it worked

Comment: Glad to know! :)